# Regex to match string followed by varying formats

Tags: regex

I am working with data from a DB which produces information on transactions.

The problem is that transactions can have any number of related attributes, and transaction details will be replicated with a new line for each attribute.

In the format of:

[Transaction ID] [tab] [Attribute name] [tab] [Attribute value] [tab] [date]

Example:

```
11111    Amount    12000
11111    Reference    101010
11111    Operator    John
11111    Subject    Credit
11111    Notes    XXXXXXXX
11112    Amount    75000
11112    Reference    202020
11112    Operator    Will
```

I am trying to identify a REGEX expression for EACH attribute which will match on the following logic;

**"Amount"** - followed by **TAB** - followed by **variable length number** - followed by **TAB**

**"Reference"** - followed by **TAB** - followed by **variable length number** - followed by **TAB**

**"Operator"** - followed by **TAB** - followed by **variable length string** - followed by **TAB**

**"Subject"** - followed by **TAB** - followed by **variable length string**- followed by TAB

**"Notes"** - followed by **TAB** - followed by **variable length string**- followed by **TAB**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer applies more to reading all attributes that belong to the same transaction id. Take a look at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xRizxb/4)

```
(?s)                                    // dot matches newline
(?<tid>\d+)                             // transactionid 
\t
(?:Amount\t(?<amount>\d+))              // amount
.\1\t                                   // newline, transactionid, tab
(?:Reference\t(?<ref>\d+))              // reference
.\1\t                                   // newline, transactionid, tab
(?:Operator\t(?<ope>\w+))               // operator
(?:.\1\t(?:Subject\t(?<sub>\w+)))?      // possible subject
(?:.\1\t(?:Notes\t(?<not>\w+)))?        // possible notes
(?!\1)                                  // negative lookahead
```

For a simple explanation, you want to read attributes until the transaction id is a different one.

Answer (score 0):

A regex like this

```
(?<transactionid>\d+)\t(?<attribute>Amount|Reference|Operator|Subject|Notes)\t(?<value>\w+)
```

will do.

Look at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xRizxb/1)

Explanation:

```
(?<transactionid>\d+)                                   // transaction id
\t                                                      // followed by tab
(?<attribute>Amount|Reference|Operator|Subject|Notes)   // attribute
\t                                                      // followed by tab
(?<value>\w+)                                           // value
```

Comment: Does this mean that I would use the following:
(?<transactionid>\d+)\t(?<amount>)\t(?<value>\w+)
(?<transactionid>\d+)\t(?<reference>)\t(?<value>\w+)
(?<transactionid>\d+)\t(?<operator>)\t(?<value>\w+)
(?<transactionid>\d+)\t(?<subject>)\t(?<value>\w+)
(?<transactionid>\d+)\t(?<notes>)\t(?<value>\w+)

Comment: Hold on, this possibly changes your original question. Your question could mean that you want to read all attributes in one go. I'll create a new example on regex101.

Comment: I've left out the named grouping to simplify the regex. Now the question is: is your input just 1 big string containing several lines with the different attributes? Your original question has a 'tab date', so can you show me the complete input? Look at https://regex101.com/r/xRizxb/3 for the simplified version.

Comment: Added another answer because I think a misunderstood your original question. Let me know which one is more appropriate.